# About proof of Morley's theorem

Tags: geometry, field-theory

I am trying to understand the generalized version of Morely's theorem proved in [this paper by Alain Connes](http://www.alainconnes.org/docs/morley.pdf).

I am stuck at the step where the generalized version is specialized for the field $\mathbb{C}.$

I will use the notation from the paper. I am not able to understand what exactly is $g_1.$ The paper tells it is "the rotation with center
$A$ and angle $2a$". So I assume $$g_1(x) = (x-A)e^{i2a}$$ But this does not seem to add up because I do not obtain $g_1^3g_2^3g_3^3=1.$

I think my understanding is wrong, can someone please explain what exactly is the affine transform $g_1.$

Comment: The rotation with center $A$ and angle $2a$ is $x \mapsto (x-A) e^{i2a} + A$, you forgot the last term (needed to take $A$ to $A$).

Comment: Cross-posted to MathOF: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/285699/about-proof-of-morleys-theorem